# How to pass whole properties of an object inside params using dapper.net

Tags: c#, .net, object, parameter-passing, dapper

I am just starting to use Dapper for my projects and 
I just cant find a way to pass an object as a parameter in Dapper.Net

Is there any way of any process to pass object as parameter then Dapper will map the object properties to the parameterized S.Q.L?

instead of using this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Product product = new Product()
    {
        Name = "DHS - 3 Star Ball",
        Price = 11,
        Category = "Table Tennis",
        Description = "ITTF - Approved Table Tennis Ball",
        ProductID = 1
    };

    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = ...ConnectionStrings)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Products (Properties here) VALUES (@Properties)";
        dbConnection.Execute(query, ...product.properties here sample: product.ProductID); //<------- Is there any substitute to this?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that you can do that only dapper but with the Dapper.Contrib.
Dapper.Contrib contains  usefull extentions like

```
T Get<T>(id);
IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
int Insert<T>(T obj);
int Insert<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Update<T>(T obj);
bool Update<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Delete<T>(T obj);
bool Delete<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool DeleteAll<T>();
```

for more information you can take a look at [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib)

With the help of Dapper.contrib ,you can do that something like this without even write sql query and pass the parameters

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var usr = new User()
            {

                Email = "testmail",
                Name = "testname"
            };

            var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainDb"].ConnectionString;
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
            dbConnection.Open();
                long insert = dbConnection.Insert<User>(usr);
            }
        }
    }

    [Table("[User]")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sakir! I will look up to the link you gave me. It is very helpful and the code is the word itself.. DAPPER! :D